# How do I create a geo-tagged event feed?

Tags: xml, calendar, geolocation, rss, atom-feed

What is the most standards compliant way to make a geo-tagged event feed that is also consumable by Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a couple days, but if anyone else is interested my solution is to create an RSS feed and use the xCal and geo Namespaces like so

```
<item>
    <title></title>
    <description></description>
    <link></link>
    <geo:lat></geo:lat>
    <geo:long></geo:long>
    <xCal:summary></xCal:summary>
    <xCal:dtstart></xCal:dtend>
    <xCal:dtend></xCal:dtend>
    <xCal:location></xCal:location>
</item>
```